# Pass data from activity to fragment not load in first time

Tags: android, fragment

I am trying to pass data from an activity to a fragment. I have four tab. The data has been passed but not shown for the first time, when I swipe other three tabs and get back to the first tab then the data are shown. I call the JSON data parsing method in the onCreate method of the activity. Here I Provide my code.
This is the Main@Activity.java

```
    package com.example.iqbal.privateuniversityinfo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

// https://api.myjson.com/bins/lb6b8

// new https://api.myjson.com/bins/1gzo6k
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String name, fac_and_sub, tution_fees, admission_info, contact;
    private String div;
    private int pos;

    private RequestQueue mqueue;
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private Bundle bundle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        div = getIntent().getStringExtra("div");
        pos = Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getStringExtra("pos"));

        bundle = new Bundle();
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        jsonParse();
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main2, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.university_details, container, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            switch (position) {

                case 0:
                    FacultyAndSubject facultyAndSubject = new FacultyAndSubject();
                    facultyAndSubject.setArguments(bundle);
                    return facultyAndSubject;
                case 1:
                    TutionFees tutionFees = new TutionFees();
                    return tutionFees;
                case 2:
                    Admission_info admission_info = new Admission_info();
                    return admission_info;
                case 3:
                    Contact contact = new Contact();
                    return contact;

                default:
                    return null;
            }


        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 4 total pages.
            return 4;
        }
    }

    private void jsonParse() {
        String url = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/1gzo6k";
        mqueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);

                        switch (div) {
                            case "ctg":
                                if (i == pos) {
                                    name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                                    fac_and_sub = jsonObject.getString("faculty_and_sub");
                                    tution_fees = jsonObject.getString("tution_fees");
                                    admission_info = jsonObject.getString("admission_info");
                                    contact = jsonObject.getString("contact");

                                    bundle.putString("name", name);
                                    bundle.putString("fac", fac_and_sub);
                                    bundle.putString("fees", tution_fees);
                                    bundle.putString("info", admission_info);
                                    bundle.putString("contact", contact);
                                }
                                break;


                        }


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });

        mqueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }
}
```

Here the FacultyAndSubject class

```
   package com.example.iqbal.privateuniversityinfo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;

public class FacultyAndSubject extends Fragment {
    Context context;
    TextView tv;
    String name, fac, fees, info, contact;
    private Bundle bundle;
    private RequestQueue mqueue;
    String div;
    int pos;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.faculty_and_subject, container, false);
        tv = v.findViewById(R.id.tv);

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            name = getArguments().getString("name");
            fac = getArguments().getString("fac");
            fees = getArguments().getString("fees");
            info = getArguments().getString("info");
            contact = getArguments().getString("contact");
        }

        tv.setText(name + "\n" + " " + fac + "\n" + fees + "\n" + info + "\n" + contact);
        return v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the code inside the `case 0`  of your `switch` as same in your default case too.

Also as suggested by @babich try setting the adapter after getting the response.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to set your viewPager after you get the data?
Add log-message of finish to your `onResponse` end and add it to your `onCreateView` of `FacultyAndSubject`

Than check what calls earlier.
Do you know how to add Log-messages and how to use `LogCat`?

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    FacultyAndSubject facultyAndSubject;
    TutionFees tutionFees;
    Admission_info admission_info;
    Contact contact;

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {

            case 0:
                if(facultyAndSubject == null) {
                facultyAndSubject = new FacultyAndSubject();
                facultyAndSubject.setArguments(bundle);
                }
                return facultyAndSubject;
            case 1:
                if(tutionFees == null) tutionFees = new TutionFees();
                return tutionFees;
            case 2:
                if(admission_info == null) admission_info = new Admission_info();
                return admission_info;
            case 3:
                if(contact == null) contact = new Contact();
                return contact;

            default:
                return null;
        }


    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 4 total pages.
        return 4;
    }
}
```

The first:

```
@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.faculty_and_subject, container, false);
        tv = v.findViewById(R.id.tv);

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            this.name = getArguments().getString("name");
            this.fac = getArguments().getString("fac");
            this.fees = getArguments().getString("fees");
            this.info = getArguments().getString("info");
            this.contact = getArguments().getString("contact");
            updateData();
        } else showLoading();

        tv.setText(name + "\n" + " " + fac + "\n" + fees + "\n" + info + "\n" + contact);

        return v;
    }

    public void updateData(String name, String fac, String fees, String info, String contact) {
    stopLoading();
    this.name = name;
    this.fac = fac;
    this.fees = fees;
    this.info = info;
    this.contact = contact;
    }
```

The second:

```
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);

                    switch (div) {
                        case "ctg":
                            if (i == pos) {
                                name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                                fac_and_sub = jsonObject.getString("faculty_and_sub");
                                tution_fees = jsonObject.getString("tution_fees");
                                admission_info = jsonObject.getString("admission_info");
                                contact = jsonObject.getString("contact");
                                if(mSectionsPagerAdapter.facultyAndSubject != null) {


                                mSectionsPagerAdapter.facultyAndSubject.
                                updateDate(name, fac, fees, info, contact) 
                                } else  {
                                mSectionsPagerAdapter.facultyAndSubject = new FacultyAndSubject();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("name", name);
                                bundle.putString("fac", fac_and_sub);
                                bundle.putString("fees", tution_fees);
                                bundle.putString("info", admission_info);
                                bundle.putString("contact", contact);
            facultyAndSubject.setArguments(bundle);
                                }
                            }
                            break;


                    }


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: 09-04 00:27:51.175 6747-6747/com.example.iqbal.privateuniversityinfo E/AAA: FacultyAndSubject call
09-04 00:28:02.386 6747-6747/com.example.iqbal.privateuniversityinfo E/AAA: onResponse finished

Comment: First call the FacultyAndSubject that's why it gets null for the first time

Comment: can you pls tell how to set viewPager?@zhebzhik

Comment: I think you must to check in FacultyAndSubject that there is no data and if there is still no data than to show loading spinner. This is the best solution in this case. And one more thing. It will be better if you declare your fragments globally and create them if `fragment == null`. And in your `jsonParse` check again that `FacultyAndSubject` is not null. If it null than create it with data and if it is not null than update data.